How to search for headlines that does not have tags?
How to display only the headlines that does not have tags? If the headline has tags then consider its children's to be tagged.

See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/73604/is-there-a-way-to-search-tag-header-without-agenda-in-org-mode for some information and https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/73604/is-there-a-way-to-search-tag-header-without-agenda-in-org-mode for a possible search (although I think he meant -{.+}, not -{.*}, but I haven't tried it yet). This method obeys tag inheritance.
